# Creating a dynamic Cstring

Tags: c++, cstring

I am facing this position where I need to create a dynamic string of user-inputted size (so I tried used a dynamic cstring).

```
char * S;
int x;

cin >> x;

S = new char[x];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    S[i]=' ';        //trying to make it a string of spaces so I can fill it in later
}
```

upon doing this and outputting the string `(cout << S;)` I am getting x spaces and some random characters how do I solve this?

Comment: Try adding a `'\0'` to the end of your string.

Comment: Why not use a std::string? Also CString is a class made by Microsoft, char* is what you have there.

Comment: @olevegard I think he meant to say 'C string'.

Answer (score 1):

Extending my previous comment out.  I think you need to add a null character to the end so that `std::cout` knows when to stop, otherwise it will just keep trying to print the memory contents that `S` points to.

```
char * S;
int x;
cin >> x;
S = new char [x + 1]; // +1 for the null character

int i;
for (i=0; i<(x); i++)
  S[i] = ' ';

S[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: thanks @austin :D I forgot about the null